# Can you pass somehow Shopify API Key and Password through fetch to get data from Shopify API orders, etc

Tags: javascript, shopify, fetch-api, shopify-api

I have a problem with my JavaScript fetch when I try to run it on the live Shopify store I get this error:

> {"errors":"[API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)"}.

Can I somehow pass API key and Password through fetch and get data back from Shopify API REST orders, products, etc.. Here is how code looks now.

```
   let apiRequest = '';

   /*************************************
    *    Shopify REST API INFORMATION
    ************************************/
    let apiOrderVersion = '/admin/api/2021-10/orders.json';
    let apiProductVersion = `/admin/api/2021-10/products/`;
    let apiProductVariantVersion = `/admin/api/2021-10/variants/`;
    /*************************************
    *    Shopify STORE INFORMATION
    ************************************/
    let store_url = 'https://storename.myshopify.com';
    let apiKey = 'apikey';
    let password = 'password';
    let limit = 250; // Limit of getting products orders
    let fromDate = '2020-01-01'; // Get date from products orders
    let toDate = '2021-10-25'; // Get to date from porducts orders

    if(limit){
        apiRequest = `${store_url}${apiOrderVersion}?limit=${limit}`;
    }
    
    if (fromDate){
        apiRequest = `${store_url}${apiOrderVersion}?created_at_min=${fromDate}`;
    }

    if (toDate){
        apiRequest = `${store_url}${apiOrderVersion}?created_at_max=${toDate}`;
    }
    
    if (limit && fromDate){
        apiRequest = `${store_url}${apiOrderVersion}?limit=${limit}&created_at_min=${fromDate}`;
    } 
    
    if (limit && toDate){
        apiRequest = `${store_url}${apiOrderVersion}?limit=${limit}&created_at_max=${toDate}`;
    }
    
    if (fromDate && toDate){
        apiRequest = `${store_url}${apiOrderVersion}?created_at_min=${fromDate}&created_at_max=${toDate}`;
    } 
    
    if (limit && fromDate && toDate) {
        apiRequest = `${store_url}${apiOrderVersion}?limit=${limit}&created_at_min=${fromDate}&created_at_max=${toDate}`
    }else{
        apiRequest = `${store_url}${apiOrderVersion}`;
    }

    console.log(apiRequest);

    fetch(apiRequest, {
            mode: 'no-cors',
            cache: 'no-cache',
            withCredentials: true,
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            crossdomain: true,
            redirect: 'follow', 
            agent: null, 
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(`${apiKey}:${password}`)
            }
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((orders) => {
                orders['orders'].forEach((order) => {
                    // console.log(`Orders: `, order);
                    // We get all order details and now from then we push to arrays finded product id and variant id it must be the same arrays length //
                    order['line_items'].forEach((line) => {
                        productsIds.push(line['product_id']);
                        variantsIds.push(line['variant_id']);
                    });
                });
                // Clearning null, duplicates and empty values //
                let products = productsIds.filter((a) => a);
                let variants = variantsIds.filter((a) => a);
    
                products = [...new Set(products)];
                variants = [...new Set(variants)];
    
                console.log(`Products ids: `, products);
                console.log(`Variants ids: `, variants);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
                alert(error);
            });
```

Answer (score -2):

Your question is super confusing. You have to inform us of what API you are trying to use here. Admin, Storefront? If Admin, OK, how do expect that query to work when you have no URL specified? In fact, same goes for Storefront with that token.

Comment: I use Admin API

Comment: Look now I edited posted code